# Underscore contains based on object property

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I would like to use Underscore.js to determine if an instance of an object is present in an array.

An example usage would be:

```
var enrollments = [
    { userid: 123, courseid: 456, enrollmentid: 1 },
    { userid: 123, courseid: 456, enrollmentid: 2 },
    { userid: 921, courseid: 621, enrollmentid: 3 }
]
```

I want to be able to identify unique an enrollment where the userid and courseid are the same.

So basically, given a list of enrollments I can remove duplicates based on matches to the userid and courseid, but not the enrollment id.

Comment: You want to just remove the duplicates? Or actually go in and find them?

Comment: [`_.uniq`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)?

Comment: @Bergi _.uniq worked in this specific instance great.  But I'm still looking to see if there is a way to determine if it exists within it.

Comment: what would be if i want to remove the duplicates matching some object properties the userid and courseid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `filter` method from [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#filter):

```
function contains(arr, userid, courseid){

 var matches = _.filter(arr, function(value){ 
    if (value.userid == userid && value.courseid == courseid){ 
      return value;
    } 
 });

 return matches;
}

contains(enrollments, 123, 456);
```

Comment: Using `_.where` for that seems easier

Comment: close... _.findWhere(enrollments, {userid: 123, enrollmentid: 1})

Comment: @Bergi you are right, but well `where` use internally `filter`

Comment: @moderndegree `findWhere` only return the first, not all

Comment: @Jonathan Naguin, that is what makes it a better solution. The OP just wanted to know if it "contains" an item. A findWhere will bail out once it is found. a filter will continue iterating the entire list.

Comment: @moderndegree in the code sample that @claydiffrient posted there are 2 object with the same `userid` and `courseid`, so if he wants to delete them, the function has to return both objects... (or it's how I understood the question)